# References in XAML don't work after migration to .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-6.0, arcgis

I am migrating a WPF application from .NET framework 4.8 to .NET 6 using a [migrating tool provided by the template](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProConcepts-3.0-Migration-Guide). The app has one main project and several supporting projects. As the solution is nested, I had to first remove the supporting projects, migrate the main project, and then reintegrate the supporting projects. Eventually all of the projects were successfully migrated to .NET 6 with the warnings:

```
Warning: Your 2.x assembly name [CommunityVizProModule] doesn't match the default .NET 6 assembly name (same as the project name), which is now [CommunityVizProAddIn]. The Migration overwrote the VS default AssemblyName setting.

Warning: Your 2.x namespace [CommunityVizProModule] doesn't match the default .NET 6 namespace (same as the project name with ' ' replaced by '_'), which is now [CommunityVizProAddIn]. The Migration overwrote the VS default namespace setting.
```

After migration, the projects lost necessary dependencies and encountered hundreds of compilation errors. I managed to fix the dependencies and resolved some of the compilation errors related to the SDK. However there is one type of major issue blocking me. In the XAML files, there are errors complaining `The name xxx does not exist the the namespace "clr-namespace:xxx.xxx".` I am sure the classes exist in the name space. Visual Studio even pops up the class names as hint when I type. The screenshot provided is an example.

I tried to build as Debug, Release. Cleaned the whole solution. Reboot the system. But still have the errors. What else should I check?

[image]

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, a completely different runtime. You can't use .NET Framework libraries in .NET Core projects. The ESRI guide only talks about migrating ArcGIS, not migrating WPF apps from .NET Framework to .NET Core. That's covered in [*Microsoft*'s upgrade documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/migration/?view=netdesktop-6.0), using Microsoft tools. The error itself complains about a missing `CommunityVizPro` library. What is this? Googling for it returns nothing. Is it your own code? Have you upgraded it to .NET 6, or at least .NET Standard 2 ?

Comment: You can use Visual Studio's [Upgrade Assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant) to find out if there are any blockers to migration and automatically migrate whatever is possible and get a list of things that need manual upgrading

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, what I am building is an ArcGIS Addin. It's a template based on WPF. I used the migration tool provided by Esri for ArcGIS Addin instead of the Microsoft  tool because ArcGIS Addins is like customized WPF and the tool takes care of .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 as well as the upgrades related to the SDK and configurations. The CommunityVizPro is my application. And yes I am using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6 works fine.

Comment: That doesn't invalidate what I said. I bet you didn't manually edit your `csproj` file which means you used Visual Studio's `Upgrade`. The warnings tell you that the namespace has changed now. `Your 2.x assembly name [CommunityVizProModule] doesn't match the default .NET 6 assembly name (same as the project name), which is now [CommunityVizProAddIn]. The Migration overwrote the VS default AssemblyName setting.` and `Your 2.x namespace [CommunityVizProModule] doesn't match the default .NET 6 namespace (same as the project name with ' ' replaced by '_'), which is now [CommunityVizProAddIn].`

Comment: The `local` and `controls` namespaces do *not* use the name in the warning, `CommunityVizProAddIn`. They use the old name

Comment: Instead of just editing the namespace, I'd suggest creating a *new* dummy WPF project in .NET Framework with a couple of screens, maybe a class library as well, and migrating it to .NET 6, to find out what breaks. It's easier to fix things when you migrate only one technology at a time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the suggestions! After some explores and tests, the problem somehow is solved...without a single change of code or dependency... I can't explain it but it just happened. Maybe there were cached references or something? I am a newbie of WPF so your suggestions and the way you consider the problems are very helpful to me. Thank yo again!